# How to get formatted total amount programmatically?

Tags: 7, commerce

I want to get the formatted total amount of my cart items.

I used the following code

```
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$line_items = $wrapper->commerce_line_items;
$total = commerce_line_items_total($line_items);
```

It returns me `$4000` instead of `$40.00`.

On shoping cart page it display `$40.00`. How can I get the price in this format?

I want this in commerce way not some custom php like `number_format` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved this issue by **dividing the total by 100**. You can see the total amount in the `field_revision_commerce_total` table. After dividing, I used `commerce_currency_format($amount,NULL,NULL)` to get the currency format.

Comment: Does not need to divide by 100. Used the following code and its done.
`$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
        $line_items = $wrapper->commerce_line_items;
        $total = commerce_line_items_total($line_items);
$total_amount = commerce_currency_format($total['amount'], $total['currency_code']);`

Comment: Yes it's working.

Comment: Ahmad, could you post your result as an answer so it's formatted better? will help others

Comment: $mysql=db_query("SELECT commerce_total_amount ,commerce_total_currency_code FROM `field_revision_commerce_total` WHERE entity_id =$order_id");
$data1 = $mysql->fetchObject();
$total_amount=$data1->commerce_total_amount;
$currency_code=$data1->commerce_total_currency_code;

print commerce_currency_format($total_amount,$currency_code);

Comment: $line_item=commerce_order_load($order_id);
$total_amount=$line_item->commerce_order_total['und'][0]['amount'];
$currency_code=$line_item->commerce_order_total['und'][0]['currency_code'];
 print commerce_currency_format($total_amount,$currency_code);

Answer (score 0):

Floats are inherently inaccurate, and thus unsuitable to use for money. Operations on accurate decimal types are very slow, and there is no guarantee all databases will do them right, some might use floats internally anyway, and only pretend. And `money` format is not popular, and is known to be sometimes implemented in a buggy way in some database engines. That leaves integers.

All you need to do is divide by 100 before you use it, and multiply by 100 before save. That's all, no more philosophy behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

```
commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($amount, $currency_code);
```

`$amount`: The price to convert to a decimal value.

`$currency_code`: The currency code of the price whose decimals value will be used to divide by the proper divisor when converting the amount.